# Persistent header and footer with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Let's assume that we have Dialog with RecyclerView.

So we can simplify the layout to this:

```
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="@color/gray"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="@color/gray"/>
```

What I'm trying to achieve are divider lines above and below recycler view.

Here is exactly how it should look like:

[image: Screenshot]

But as I mentioned it is in the dialog, and size of content in RecyclerView is changing, so it works perfectly when content is small, but when content is bigger than max height of dialog, last divider line is hiding below recycler view content.

I was trying to solve that by putting in everything in relative layout and align to bottom last divider, but problem is inversing, I mean it works when content is bigger than max height of dialog, but it's not working with smaller content because there is empty space between recycler view and last divider.

Every help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried setting `android:maxHeight` to your `RecyclerView`?

Comment: No, thank you, I think it's working now. You can add answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your dialog layout with following xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Yep, this solved my issue. I don't know why, but it's working. Could you explain?

Comment: layout_weight specifies how much of the remaining space in the layout to be allocated to the View. Here i have given the value as 1 which means it will take remaining total space.Please refer this http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight

Comment: i think you have to make the android:layout_height property as wrap_content for Recycler view to make the view look as expected when the content is small.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `android:maxHeight` to your `RecyclerView`

Comment: I made a mistake, actually it's not working when the content is too big.

Comment: Maybe make `RecyclerView` height to match parent? That way it should occupy the space between your lines.